# Swagger UI sending "BearerToken" in header, need "Bearer"

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, apigee

I'm making a swagger-UI using swagger 2.0 generated in the integrated Apigee portal.

I'm trying to get the oauth2 client credentials(in swagger 2.0 called application) flow to work in the "try it out" part of the UI.

Note that the input from the user is the clientid and secret, and not the token.

When I try to authorize a get operation and send requests, I can see in the curl representation of the UI that the Authorization header is expressed "Authorization: BearerToken {token}". The token is replaced in the curl string as expected.

Apigee does not support the "BearerToken" prefix, only "Bearer". 
Is there a way to force swaggerUI to use the prefix "Bearer" instead of "BearerToken"?

My securitydefinition:

```
securityDefinitions:
  OAuth2:
    type: oauth2
    flow: application
    tokenUrl: 'https://{org-environment}/token'
    scopes:
      read: Grants read access
```

My security definition in the path:

```
 paths:
  /resources:
    get:
      security:
        - OAuth2: [read]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the token is set from the response the oauth access token generation proxy.

I changed the token.type from "BearerToken" to "Bearer" and this solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you. https://community.apigee.com/questions/46681/edge-generating-the-wrong-oauth20-token-type.html